# Possible to have nested reusable UICollectionViewCells

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I take great care to use custom reusable `UICollectionViewCell`s with a `ReuseIdentifier` so that cell subviews do not have to be recreated but only have to be refilled and resized with new data each time.

I now have a complex custom `UICollectionViewCell` with a group of subviews that can get repeated X times, depending on the data. So a part of the cell can be repeated 1 to n times. This part has a couple of subviews and right now I recreate them every single time if I fill a reused cell with new data. This creates a heavy processing load and is quite dumb.

Is it possible to create a separate `UICollectionViewCell` with only this subpart and then include it with a `ReuseIdentifier` X times in my parent `UICollectionViewCell` thus benefiting from reusing this subpart and not having to recreate all the subviews of this subpart every single time?

Or in simpler terms, is it possible to nest a `UICollectionViewCell` in `UICollectionViewCell`s and benefit from the reusing mechanism of iOS?

Comment: Could a solution be to use a custom `UICollectionReusableView` in a `UICollectionViewCell`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could nest a UICollectionView (or UITableView) within a UICollectionViewCell. This might be simpler than the subview scheme you are using now.

Your UICollectionViewCell would need to implement the delegate and data source methods for the nested collection view (or table view).

Do not confuse the nested collection view with the collection view to which your parent UICollectionViewCell belongs. Don't mix reuse identifiers, in other words.

Comment: Will the individual nested `UICollectionView`s share a pool of cells between them? ie are `UICollectionViewCell`s with the same re-use identifiers re-used across different `UICollectionView` instances?

Answer (score 0):

**You can call the [UICollectionView refreshdata] in the dequeue method for (outer) UICollectionView**

Comment: Sorry can you elaborate a bit more what you exactly mean?